Multivariable taylor - why does $R_k(a) = o(||h||^k)$
Let $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^k$ for $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open. Choose $a \in E$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a + h \in E$. Then $\exists \theta \in (0,1)$ such that $f(a + h) = f(a) + (D_hf)(a) + ... + \frac{(D_h^{k-1}f)(a)}{(k-1)!} + \frac{(D_h^kf(a + \theta h))}{k!}$. Show that $R_k(h) := \frac{(D_h^kf(a + \theta h))}{k!} = o(\|h\|^k)$ for $h \to 0$.
We have $\| R_k(h) - \frac{(D_h^kf(a))}{k!}\| = \frac{1}{k!}\|(D_h^kf)(a + \theta h) - (D_h^kf)(a)\| = \frac{1}{k!}\|\sum_{j_1,...,j_k = 1}^n ((D_{j_1...j_k}f)(a + \theta h) - (D_{j_1...j_k}f)(a))h_{j_1}...h_{j_k}\|$. I don't understand my syllabus from this point on. How do I finish the proof?

It looks like you have an unbalanced number of $|$s in one of your equations
